# Download csv file from website which require authentication using SSIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to download a csv file from a Website which requires Login and Password using HTTP Connection Manager and Scrip Task but I just seem clueless and I have googled and I have had so many different approaches and I have tried and not succeeded.

I have managed to create HTTP Connection Manager with the link and Login and Password details and the Test Connection Succeeded. I have no clue how to write a script in Script Task which can download a csv file?

URL: https://feedback.X.X.X/practice/d8d44935/consult_admin_view and I need to click on the page to download the csv file but that doesn't have its own URL address.

The folder I need to download is C:\temp

Apologies if I sound too vague or clueless.

Comment: Does "click on the page to download" trigger a HTTP POST request? Does it cause some kind of JavaScript/AJAX call to occur? If we can figure out what clicking does behind-the-scenes, we might be able to automate it.

Comment: When I right click on the csv file and go to properties it has a Http address.

Comment: Does pasting that address in a browser's address bar let you download the file?

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. Yes it does once I put in the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Visual Basic code I've used in an SSIS Script Task to achieve something similar.  It assumes your HTTP connection is named `HTTP_Test`.

`Dim mySSISConnection As Object = Dts.Connections("HTTP_Test").AcquireConnection(Nothing)
Dim myConnection As HttpClientConnection = New HttpClientConnection(mySSISConnection)
myConnection.ServerUserName = "myusername"
myConnection.ServerUserName = "mypassword"
myConnection.DownloadFile("C:\Temp\download.csv", True)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I can't get past the authentication page. My username and password is correct.

Comment: Your HTTP connection should not point to the authentication page.  It should point straight at the file you want to download.  You said this worked when you tested the HTTP definition, so it should be just a matter of setting username and password at runtime.

Comment: My HTTP connection is pointing to the csv file. I have checked my username and password and I get through beyond the login page. Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using the [PowerShell WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public void DownloadFile(
    string address,
    string fileName
)
```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlrw0dNmFdU) should help you with the Automation of your ETL Infrastructure with SSIS and PowerShell.